# OpenId 3 to OpenId 4 multiple Issuer Names

Tags: openid, asp.net-core-3.1

I am migrating from OpenId 3 to Open id 4 (part of our migration from .net 4 to .net core 3). One of the requirements is we need to have an internal and an external dns which our open id will authenticate against. We have a 3rd party hosting our Open Id Web App, who charge based on load balance consumption. To reduce this we want to be able to route the calls to the identity provider internally behind the load balancers. (annoyingly they are unable to have internal routing based on the dns, sounds suspiciously like cba however, we are where we are)

We achieved this previously by setting the issuer name, however this feature has been removed in open Id 4, and after a few hours of research I am still stuck. If anyone could help me out by pointing be to the direction of the new or an alternative way of implementing it that would be great.

We all love code so below is my external web api's configuration file

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration
    {
        DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer())
    };

    var corsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttribute);

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    // Configure Authorisation
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerUrl"],
        RequiredScopes = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerScopes"] },
        PreserveAccessToken = true,

        // This is set to convince the IdentityServer middleware to validate with the correct issuer url.
        // Only needed for APIs/services that talk to both the internal and external URLs for IdentityServer
        IssuerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerIssuerUri"],
    });

    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

and below here is the identity providers configuration options (removed all of the sensitive information)

```
// IdentityServer options
var options = new IdentityServerOptions
{
    EventsOptions = new EventsOptions
    {
        RaiseErrorEvents = true,
        RaiseFailureEvents = true,
        RaiseInformationEvents = true,
        RaiseSuccessEvents = true
    },
    SiteName = "Identity",
    SigningCertificate = primaryTokenSigningCertificate,
    SecondarySigningCertificate = secondaryTokenSigningCertificate,
    IssuerUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerIssuerUri"],
    Factory = factory,
    EnableWelcomePage = false,
    RequireSsl = SupportMethods.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RequireSsl"]),
    AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
    {
        // We use default cookie options. Otherwise override values using: CookieOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.CookieOptions(), 
        RememberLastUsername = true,
        RequireSignOutPrompt = false,
        EnableSignOutPrompt = false,
        EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
        LoginPageLinks = new List<LoginPageLink>
        {
            new LoginPageLink
            {
                Href = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ForgotPasswordUrl"],
                Text = "Forgot Password?",
                Type = "forgot-password"
            }
        }
    },
};
```